# Display image saved in voyager admin panel database on laravel view

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am developing digital Library and i want to display book data in view file, the images and books are stored using voyager in blob datatype in voyager admin panel. The images and the books are not displayed but only the book info like auther, title, isdn...i dont know where the problem is, below is the view file where i want to display book data

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-left">
   

@foreach ($books as $book)

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$book->img) }}" alt="images">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa-users"></i> {{ $book->title }}</h5>

                        <p>Auther: <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $book->auther }}</p>
                        <p>Published: <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $book->published }}</p>
                        <p>ISBN: <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ $book->isbn }}</p>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Read</a>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Borrow</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div> 
    @endforeach

</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

this is the route in web.php

```
Route::get('book_view', 'DisplayBooksController@display');
```

Comment: what is the value of `asset('images/'.$book->img)`? did you dd it?

Answer (score 0):

try this -

`{{ Storage::url($book->img) }}`